# Сортировка хеша

Tags: perl

Допустим у меня есть хеш такого вида :

```
 my %hash = ('Андрей' => 3, 'Вася' => 2, 'Петя' => 5, 'Коля' => 2, 'Женя' => 4);
```

И мне нужно вывести элементы с минимальным значение из него . То есть результат должен быть

> Вася 2
>
> Коля 2

Собственно как можно это реализовать более рационально ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если сортировать значения и потом выбирать минимальные:

```
my $min;
for my $name (sort { $hash{$a} <=> $hash{$b} } keys %hash) {
    my $value = $hash{$name};
    last if defined($min) && $min != $value;
    $min = $value;
    print "$name $value\n";
}
```

Если не сортировать:

```
use List::Util qw(min);
my $min = min values %hash;
while(my ($name, $value) = each %hash) {
    print "$name $value\n" if $value == $min;
}
```

Если сортировать имена:

```
use List::Util qw(min);
my $min = min values %hash;
for my $name (sort grep { $hash{$_} == $min } keys %hash) {
    print "$name $min\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

не правильно, cmp сортирует строки, а тут числа. Надо использовать оператор сравнения (<=>):

```
my $min;
foreach my $key (sort { ($hash{$a} <=> $hash{$b}) || ($a cmp $b) } keys %hash) {
    if (!defined $min) {
        $min = $hash{$key};
    }
    elsif ($hash{$key} != $min) {
        last;
    }
    print "$key $hash{$key}\n";
}
```

Comment: Да, поправил оператор, спасибо.